# Stored procedure to check existing value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The table project has 5 project id's. The stored procedure has a parameter as `@projectid`. If user execute the stored procedure with the parameter 6 it should return 'project 6 does not exist'.

```
projectid
---------
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

This is what I am trying

```
create procedure chk_project @projectid int 
as begin
if 
@projectid!=(select projectid from project where projectid=@projectid)
print @projectid+'does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may help you

```
  create procedure Usp_project
  (
      @projectid int
  )
  As
  /*
  Exec Usp_project 6
  */
  if not exists(select projectid from project where projectid = @projectid)
  begin
      print('Projectid does not Exist')
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this as:

```
create procedure chk_project(
    @projectid int 
) as
begin
    if not exists (select 1 from project where projectid = @projectid)
        print cast(@projectid as varchar) + ' does not exist';
end;
```

Comment: when i execute it ,it returns command(s) execute successfully instead of printing does not exit thin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Create procedure chk_project
@projectid int 
as
begin
    if not exists (select 1 from project where projectid = @projectid)
    begin
        print cast(@projectid as varchar) + ' does not exist';
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, This SP would return output as resultset

```
CREATE PROCEDURE chk_project (@projectid INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM project
            WHERE projectid = @projectid
            )
        SELECT cast(@projectid AS VARCHAR) + ' does not exist' as Status;
    ELSE
        SELECT cast(@projectid AS VARCHAR) + '  exist' as Status;
END;
```